# How was this flag handled?

Tags: support, flags

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25452834/827263) (which the poster deleted). The poster and I got into a bit of an argument in comments. The poster deleted the answer himself. Two unrelated answers of mine from last year were downvoted within a few minutes of that.

The point of the flag was to ask the mods to look into it. I did not, and do not, make any accusations.

The flag was marked as "helpful". My question here: was any action taken on this flag, beyond marking it as helpful? I note that the downvotes are still in place.

To be clear, I'm not complaining about the downvotes (I don't think they were deserved, but two downvotes aren't worth worrying about), nor am I asking that any particular action should be taken. This is mostly a question about procedures.

If you can't go into detail because of privacy concerns, I'll accept that.

Comment: interesting how this is voted down without explaining what's wrong with the question

Comment: There's a fair amount of flag handling which is done as a side-effect of other actions (i.e. the flag is declined or marked helpful without someone evaluating the *flag* as a *flag*). I believe that *two* votes --- even coming from a single user against a single user and done in a short time span --- will not be enough to trigger the serial voting reversal code.

Comment: @Louis: I believe that the OP would have used an "other" flag, which would not be subject to auto-dismissal. The moderator who handled the flag probably could not find enough evidence to prove that it was serial downvoting, but believed that the flag had merit. From my experience, two downvotes are indeed not enough to trigger the serial downvoting script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not the one who handled the flag, but it's pretty easy to guess the thought process here. Your flag was probably marked as helpful because there were some rude comments on that post that were deleted (and some remain, but the whole post is deleted so there's not much point in deleting individual comments).

We can't really do anything about the two downvotes because we can't see who cast individual votes. We only get access to patterns of voting behavior, so someone would have to go on a more extended downvoting campaign before a moderator would be able to step in. The most we can do at this point is make an annotation in a user's account detailing the suspicious behavior, so if it becomes a pattern other moderators have more data to work with.